# Stripe elements with ajax not working on firefox and safari mobile

Tags: php, ajax, stripe-payments

I am using stripe elements with an ajax call to pass more data to a php file once payment is successful. It works great on all browsers on PC and mobile except for FIREFOX and SAFARI on MOBILE only.I get no errors in console or remote debugging but the POST URL in ajax is simply not being called.
The payment is always successful and the redirect to thenkyou.ph page is always working well passing the paymentIntentId. Just the AJAX call on firefox and safari mobile is not calling the URL in post

Here is the code ...

```
print("<form  id='payment-form'  method='post'>");

 print("<input  type='text' name='name_on_ticket_1' id='name_on_ticket_1' value='' class='admin_input_text'/>");

 print("<button id='submit'   type='submit' name='submit'>");
        print("<div class='spinner hidden' id='spinner'></div>
        <span id='button-text'>".$lang['submit_payment']."</span>
      </button>");
      print("</form>");

      print("<p id='card-error' role='alert'></p>
      <p class='result-message hidden' style='width: 100%; text-align: center;'>
        Payment succeeded
        <br>
           ".$lang['redirecting_you']." <a href='' target='_blank'> .. </a>
           <br>
          <img src='/images/spinner.gif'>
      </p>");

print("<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
//  event.preventDefault();
//  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // or iPhones don't get fresh data
    
    
      var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_mYn ...xxxxx'); // test publishable API key


 
// The items the customer wants to buy
var purchase = {
  items: [{ id: 'cart' }],
 
          paymentMethodType: 'card',
          phone: '".$client_phone."',
          email: '".$user_email."',
          full_client_name: '".$client_name." ".$client_name_last."',
          currency: '".strtolower($_POST['currency'])."',
          amount: '".(round($totalone_stripe,2)*100)."',
          refund_protection: '".$refund_protection."',
          refund_protection_price: '".$refund_protection_price."',
          channel_type: '".$channel_type."',
          cart_items: '".$_POST['cart_items']."',
          client_reference_id: '".$id_client."',
          city: '".$client_city."',
          id_user: '".$user_id."',
};


// Disable the button until we have Stripe set up on the page
document.querySelector('button').disabled = true;
fetch('/stripe/create_payment.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
  
})
  .then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    var style = {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#32325d'
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
      }
    };

    var card = elements.create('card', { style: style });
    // Stripe injects an iframe into the DOM
    card.mount('#card-element');

    card.on('change', function (event) {
      // Disable the Pay button if there are no card details in the Element
      document.querySelector('button').disabled = event.empty;
      document.querySelector('#card-error').textContent = event.error ? event.error.message : '';
    });

    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Complete payment when the submit button is clicked
      payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);
      
      $('#modal').show(0);
      
    });
  });

// Calls stripe.confirmCardPayment
// If the card requires authentication Stripe shows a pop-up modal to
// prompt the user to enter authentication details without leaving your page.
var payWithCard = function(stripe, card, clientSecret) {
  loading(true);
  stripe
    .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: card
      }
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Show error to your customer
        showError(result.error.message);
      } else {
        // The payment succeeded!
        orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id);
      }
    });
};

/* ------- UI helpers ------- */

// Shows a success message when the payment is complete
var orderComplete = function(paymentIntentId) {
  loading(false);
  document
    .querySelector('.result-message a')
    .setAttribute(
      'href',
      'https://yoursite.com/thankyou.php?' + paymentIntentId
    );
  document.querySelector('.result-message').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.querySelector('button').disabled = true;

var paymId =  paymentIntentId; ");

                print("
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/stripe/payment_xx.php',
                      cache: false,
                      
                  data: {
                        payment_intent_id: paymId,   ");
    print("name_on_ticket_1 : $('#name_on_ticket_1').val(),");
 print("     },
                         
                      success: function (data) {
                          //  displayMessage('Updated Successfully');
                       }
                      

                    }); 
                    
                    // console.log(data);
                      var href = paymentIntentId;
                    setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = 'https://example.com/thankyou.php?paID=' + href; }, 0 );
                    
                    return false;
};

// Show the customer the error from Stripe if their card fails to charge
var showError = function(errorMsgText) {
  loading(false);
  var errorMsg = document.querySelector('#card-error');
  errorMsg.textContent = errorMsgText;
  setTimeout(function() {
    errorMsg.textContent = '';
  }, 4000);
  $('#modal').hide(0);
};

// Show a spinner on payment submission
var loading = function(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector('button').disabled = true;
    document.querySelector('#spinner').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.querySelector('#button-text').classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('button').disabled = false;
    document.querySelector('#spinner').classList.add('hidden');
    document.querySelector('#button-text').classList.remove('hidden');
  }
};


});
</script>");
```

```
and the create_payment.php
```

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

try {
  // retrieve JSON from POST body
  $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
  
 $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_80L3U7uxxxxxx7'); 
    
    if($json_obj->email != '') {
$customer_email_post =  $json_obj->email;
$client_name = $json_obj->full_client_name;
$client_phone = $json_obj->phone;
$client_id_user = $json_obj->id_user;
}else{
$customer_email_post = '';  
}
// check if customer exists


 $stripe_cust = \Stripe\Customer::all(['email'=>$customer_email_post, 'limit' => 1,]);
 
$stripe_cust_arr = $stripe_cust->data;
 //  var_dump($stripe_cust_arr);


for($x = 0;$x < count($stripe_cust_arr);$x++) { 
//  print(" for cust id ".$stripe_cust_arr[$x]['id']." - ".$stripe_cust_arr[$x]['email']."<br><br>");
    $customer_id_exists = $stripe_cust_arr[$x]['id'];   
}

if($customer_id_exists) {
//print(" Use customer ");

for($x = 0;$x < count($stripe_cust_arr);$x++) { 
//  print(" for cust id ".$stripe_cust_arr[$x]['id']." ");
    $customer_email_exists = $stripe_cust_arr[$x]['email'];
    $customer_from_stripe = $stripe_cust_arr[$x]['id']; 
}
    
}else{  
//print(" CREATE customer ");   
$customer_email_exists = $customer_email_post;

$customer = $stripe->customers->create([
   'name' => $client_name,
    'email' => $customer_email_exists,
     'phone' => $client_phone,
   'description' => $client_id_user,
]);

$customer_from_stripe = ($customer->id);

}

  $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
 //   'amount' => ($json_obj->items->amount),
   'amount' => $json_obj->amount,
    'currency' => $json_obj->currency,
    'customer' => $customer_from_stripe,
    'description' => $json_obj->cart_items,
    
     'metadata' => [
                 'cart_items'  => $json_obj->cart_items,
                'refund_protection' => $json_obj->refund_protection,
                'refund_protection_price' => $json_obj->refund_protection_price,
            //  'name_on_ticket_1' => $json_obj->name_on_ticket_1,
            //  'name_on_ticket_2' => $json_obj->name_on_ticket_2,
    ],
    
  ]);

  $output = [
    'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
  ];
  echo json_encode($output);

//if ($paymentIntent->status == 'succeeded') {
    
    $pay_intent = ($paymentIntent->id); 
    $pay_intent_status = ($paymentIntent->status); 
    
    $charg_data = ($paymentIntent->charges->data);
       
// $item_type = $json_obj->name_on_ticket_1;
  
 
// }
  
} catch (Error $e) {
  http_response_code(500);
  echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This is the complete working script that works for me on all PC and Mobile browsers Android and iOS. Implemented live and tested.
Note where are event.preventDefault(); and $(document).ready(function(){

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

      var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_your key'); // test publishable API key


 
// The items the customer wants to buy
var purchase = {
  items: [{ id: 'cart' }],
 
                    paymentMethodType: 'card',
          phone: '".$client_phone."',
          email: '".$user_email."',
          full_client_name: '".$client_name." ".$client_name_last."',
          currency: '".strtolower($_POST['currency'])."',
          amount: '".(round($total_stripe,2)*100)."',

        
};


// Disable the button until we have Stripe set up on the page
document.querySelector('button').disabled = true;
fetch('/stripe/create_payment.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
  
})
  .then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    var style = {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#32325d'
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
      }
    };

    var card = elements.create('card', { style: style });
    // Stripe injects an iframe into the DOM
    card.mount('#card-element');

    card.on('change', function (event) {
      // Disable the Pay button if there are no card details in the Element
      document.querySelector('button').disabled = event.empty;
      document.querySelector('#card-error').textContent = event.error ? event.error.message : '';
    });

    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Complete payment when the submit button is clicked
      payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);
      
      $('#modal').show(0);
      
    });
  });

// Calls stripe.confirmCardPayment
// If the card requires authentication Stripe shows a pop-up modal to
// prompt the user to enter authentication details without leaving your page.
var payWithCard = function(stripe, card, clientSecret) {
  loading(true);
  stripe
    .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: card
      }
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Show error to your customer
        showError(result.error.message);
      } else {
        // The payment succeeded!
        orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id);
      }
    });
};

/* ------- UI helpers ------- */

// Shows a success message when the payment is complete
var orderComplete = function(paymentIntentId) {
  loading(false);
  document
    .querySelector('.result-message a')
    .setAttribute(
      'href',yoursite.com/thankyou.php?' + paymentIntentId
    );
  document.querySelector('.result-message').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.querySelector('button').disabled = true;
  
  event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/stripe/payment_completed.php',
                     
                  data: {
                        payment_intent_id: paymentIntentId,
                                    other_var : $('#other_var').val(),  },
                         
                      success: function (data) {
                          //  displayMessage('Updated Successfully');
        setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = 'https://yoursite.com/mobile/thankyou.php?paID=' + paymentIntentId; }, 0 );
                       }
                      

                    }); 

                return false;
                    
};");

// Show the customer the error from Stripe if their card fails to charge
var showError = function(errorMsgText) {
  loading(false);
  var errorMsg = document.querySelector('#card-error');
  errorMsg.textContent = errorMsgText;
  setTimeout(function() {
    errorMsg.textContent = '';
  }, 4000);
  $('#modal').hide(0);
};

// Show a spinner on payment submission
var loading = function(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector('button').disabled = true;
    document.querySelector('#spinner').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.querySelector('#button-text').classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('button').disabled = false;
    document.querySelector('#spinner').classList.add('hidden');
    document.querySelector('#button-text').classList.remove('hidden');
  }
};


});
</script>
```